# Update Next.js query params using router

Tags: next.js

I have the following page in a next.js app: `pages/products/[category].js`. This page has a sorting system which sorts the products by price, date, title etc. Example: `http://localhost:3000/products/music?sortBy=price-asc`.

I have a select with all the options and the following `onChange`:

```js
onChange={(e) => {
  router.push({
    pathname: router.asPath, // to get the current route (`products/music`)
    query: { sortBy: e.target.value },
  });
}}
```

When I first visit the page and I have no query params added to the url, the redirect works as expected. But when I do it again, instead of replacing `sortBy`, it adds a second one.

So the url becomes: `http://localhost:3000/products/music%3FsortBy=price-asc?sortBy=price-desc`

Any way to properly update the query params?

Comment: You can refer this stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360586/next-js-add-slug-params-to-clean-url