# Next.js Add slug/params to clean URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slug, next-router

I have a structure with a clean URL in the "pages" folder like this ...

```
/pages/items/[pageNumber]/index.tsx
```

And if I use `router.push` I use it like this to get to that page ...

```
router.replace("/items/[pageNumber]", "/items/1")
```

That works great, but now I want to add a query params (for filter) to that URL, how can I do that?

I tried this ...

```
router.push(`/items/[pageNumber]/`, `/items/1/?${filterParams}`, { shallow: true });
```

But that doesn't work, and I'm wondering how to do that.

Comment: when you say it's not working, you should state how exactly. Is it that you could not get the query param or the routing is not working, etc.

Comment: @Joshua For some reason, the URL changes but the page gets refreshed after 3 seconds.

Comment: @Joshua I'm wondering is what I'm doing is correct, if it is correct, I should look for the problem elsewhere, but I'm not sure if that is correct or not.

Comment: check this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61470662/6220015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use it like this

```
router.push(`/items/[pageNumber]/`, `/items/1/?${filterParams}`, { shallow: true });
```

you are not passing query params to the page, you are only showing them in the address bar, I guess.

How about something like this:

```
router.push({
  pathname '/items/[pageNumber]/',
  query: {
    param1: 'yes',
  },
}, {
  pathname: '/items/1/',
  query: {
    param1: 'yes',
  },
});
```

Don't forget to update `query` part for your case.

Comment: Ok, but the thing is I have no idea what kind of filter params I'm going to receive, it could be ?typ=1,2, or ?type=1,2&make=2,3, so I need it to be dynamic, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know where do you get those from but, you can go with something like `{ type: '1,2' }` or `{ type: '1,2', make: '2,3' }`?

Comment: When I try your solution, the URL changes but the page refreshes itself after 3 seconds for some reason.

Comment: Well, I updated Next.js and re-ran the project and the page doesn't refresh anymore, which is good, I'll try your solution and see if it works.

Comment: Your solution worked great, and I found out why the page reloads a few seconds after the query params changes, here's the link to the issue if anyone stumbles on this thread ...
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9958